# Why is there no generic method to diff consecutive rows in pyspark dataframes/rdds?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I frequently come across the use case that I have (a time ordered) Spark dataframe with values from which I should like to know the differences between consecutive rows:

```
>>> df.show()
+-----+----------+----------+
|index|        c1|        c2|
+-----+----------+----------+
|  0.0|0.35735932|0.39612636|
|  1.0| 0.7279809|0.54678476|
|  2.0|0.68788993|0.25862947|
|  3.0|  0.645063| 0.7470685|
+-----+----------+----------+
```

The question on how to do this has been asked before in a narrower context:

[pyspark, Compare two rows in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229659/pyspark-compare-two-rows-in-dataframe)

[Date difference between consecutive rows - Pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156367/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows-pyspark-dataframe)

However, I find the answers rather involved:

- a separate module "Window" must be imported
- for some data types (datetimes) a cast must be done
- then using "lag" finally the rows can be compared

It strikes me as odd, that this cannot be done with a single API call like, for example, so:

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as f
>>> df.select(f.diffs(df.c1)).show()
+----------+
| diffs(c1)|
+----------+
|   0.3706 |
|  -0.0400 |
|  -0.0428 |
|     null |
+----------+
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: In both linked questions you can find answers using `lag` function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230813, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38159608. Can you imagine API simpler than using one function? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few basic reasons:

- In general distributed data structures used in Spark are not ordered. In particular any lineage containing shuffle phase / exchange can output a structure with non-deterministic order.

  As a result when we talk about Spark `DataFrame` we actually mean relation not `DataFrame` as known from local libraries like Pandas and without explicit ordering comparing consecutive rows is just not meaningful.
- Things are even more fuzzy when you realize that sorting methods used in Spark use shuffles and are not stable.
- If you ignore possible non-determinism handling partition boundaries is a bit involved and typically breaks lazy execution.

  In other words you cannot access an element which is left from the first element on a given partition or right from the last element of a given partition without a shuffle, an additional action or separate data scan.