# Comparing Rows in Pyspark after Grouping on Multiple Columns [PySpark][Spark]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have a dataframe with the schema :

```
Application Name
Application ID
Application Version
Mean of Metric 1
Mean of Metric 2
Mean of Metric 3
Mean of Metric 4
... (20 Metric Columns)
Standard Deviation of Metric 1
Standard Deviation of Metric 2
Standard Deviation of Metric 3
Standard Deviation of Metric 4
...(20 Metric Columns)
```

The Application Version can be `Version 1` or `Version 2`. I need to verify if the mean of a particular metric name for a particular Application Name and Application ID, in case of `Version 2`, falls within :

```
[Mean of Version 1 - Standard Deviation of Version 1, Mean of Version 1 + Standard Deviation of Version 1]
```

and add a resulting column for the Version 2 with the value as either `True` or `False`, what would be the best way to do so?

I have looked at `GroupBy`, `GroupByKey`, `ReduceByKey`, `CombineByKey`, but not able to come up with a way to do this.

Tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229659/pyspark-compare-two-rows-in-dataframe) as a reference but I seemingly cannot use any of the aggregation functions available and have to use a custom function here. Also need to do this for multiple columns.

Comment: To validate my understanding, so you want to compare the mean of Version-2 is within the mean/stdev of Version-1 for the same Application Name and ID, is that correct?